# How to get information from file with condition in Shell script without using "awk"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

i have file

```
10 -     William English 80 100 404
10 abc   William Math    50 100 501
10 xyzsd William IT      60 100 550
10 -     William Sec     60 100 401
11 -     John    English 90 100 400
11 -     John    Math    75 100 404
11 ali   John    IT      85 100 550 
11 -     John    Sec     60 100 401
```

conditions : if the 2nd column is - then 2nd condition check last column value beginning in 4 then count the Name (William and John)
Output :

```
3 John
2 William
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F ' ' '{if ($2 == "-" && $NF ~ /^4/) print $3}' <file_name> | uniq -c
```

Explanation:
We are using if statement in awk to check the two conditions:

- If 2nd element is equals to '-'
- If last element begins with 4

If above two conditions are true, we are printing name, stored in 3rd element

uniq -c will count occurrences of the names

Comment: if we want to change "$NF" to element Like $7

{if ($2 == "-" && $7== ~ /^4/) print $3}

Comment: No need of adding '==', just change NF with 7, like: {if ($2 == "-" && $7 ~ /^4/) print $3}

Comment: Plz can you give me Explanation about ~ /^4/ , how they work and why we dont need ==

Comment: Sure, /^4/ is a regular expression, it means anything that begins with "4", '^' is used for start of the string.
And '~' means 'matches', it is like 'like' operator. So, the expression will match value of $7 with /^4/, i.e., will check if $7 begins with 4 or not.

Here, we are not using ==, because we are just matching 1st character of $7, if you want to match whole value of $7, then == can be used, like if you want to check if $7 is 400, then it can be used like: {if ($2 == "-" && $7 == "400") print $3}

Comment: how can we do this without "awk",  any alternative way ?

Comment: You can loop through each line of the file, and use 'cut' and 'if' to get 2nd and 7th element and compare them. But it will be very complex, with 'awk' it is very simple

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '$2 == "-" && $NF ~ /^4/ { ++freq[$3] }
END { for (i in freq) print freq[i], i }' file
```

```
2 William
3 John
```